# How write a query to generate rows in first table based on a column value then join it with the second table?

Tags: oracle, join, plsql

I have two tables, the first one is the required job table that has a field which shows the required number for a job position, and the second table stores the job candidate with their status shows which candid is selected or not, what I want is to generate rows from the first table based on the required number, then join it with the second table of candidate that selected and rows with the empty candidate id, so the total number of returned rows is the sum of the required field in the left table. for example, if the required number of job's positions is 3 and two candidates are selected for this position then my desired result would be like this :

[image]

I write below pl-SQL code :

```
with a as (
            select * 
              from jobs j
                   ,lateral (select 1 from dual  connect by level <= j.required_number )
             where j.personnel_req_number = '50' and j.company = 'A')
, b as (
          select * 
            from candidate c
           where c.personnel_req_number = '50' and c.company = 'A' 
             and c.state = 'Appointed' )
    select *
      from a 
      left join b on a.company = b.company and a.personnel_req_number = b.personnel_req_number
```

but the result is like this :

[image: my desire result]

how can I write a query that shows my desire result? I would really appreciate if someone can help

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE candidate(company  VARCHAR2(255), 
                       personnel_req_number INTEGER, 
                       candidate_id INTEGER, 
                       state VARCHAR2(255));


CREATE TABLE jobs(company  VARCHAR2(255), 
                  personnel_req_number INTEGER, 
                  required_number INTEGER, 
                  job_id INTEGER);
```

Data:

```
insert into candidate(company, personnel_req_number, candidate_id, state ) 
    values('A', 50, 2077, 'Appointed');

insert into candidate(company, personnel_req_number, candidate_id, state ) 
    values('A', 50 , 2078, 'Appointed');

insert into candidate(company, personnel_req_number, candidate_id, state )
    values('A', 60, 2079, 'Decline');
    


insert into jobs (company, personnel_req_number, required_number, job_id ) 
    values ('A', 50, 3, 400);
```

Comment: Can you provide the tables and data (in SQL)?

Comment: Your description is very unclear. Could you describe your ultimate goal without reference to SQL processes. Also provide actual input table descriptions (ddl) and sample date - as formatted text- **no images**. See [why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). For formatting you can use [Senseful](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Copy the results from there and past between lines containing just ```.  I am voting to close pending those updates.

Comment: @davidm: I add tables' data

Comment: @Belayer: I add tables' data